# Rust: how to assign `iter().map()` or `iter().enumarate()` to same variable

Tags: rust, functional-programming, iterator, type-conversion

```rust
struct A {...whatever...};
const MY_CONST_USIZE:usize = 127;


// somewhere in function

// vec1_of_A:Vec<A> vec2_of_A_refs:Vec<&A> have values from different data sources and have different inside_item types
let my_iterator;
if my_rand_condition() { // my_rand_condition is random and compiles for sake of simplicity
    my_iterator = vec1_of_A.iter().map(|x| (MY_CONST_USIZE, &x)); // Map<Iter<Vec<A>>>
} else {
    my_iterator = vec2_of_A_refs.iter().enumerate(); // Enumerate<Iter<Vec<&A>>>
}
```

how to make this code compile?

at the end (based on condition) I would like to have iterator able build from both inputs and I don't know how to integrate these `Map` and `Enumerate` types into single variable without calling `collect()` to materialize iterator as `Vec`

reading material will be welcomed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `vec_of_A` case, first you need to replace `&x` with `x` in your map function.  The code you have will never compile because the mapping closure tries to return a reference to one of its parameters, which is never allowed in Rust.  To make the types match up, you need to dereference the `&&A` in the `vec2_of_A_refs` case to `&A` instead of trying to add a reference to the other.

Also, `-127` is an invalid value for `usize`, so you need to pick a valid value, or use a different type than `usize`.

Having fixed those, now you need some type of dynamic dispatch.  The simplest approach would be boxing into a `Box<dyn Iterator>`.

Here is a complete example:

```
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

struct A;
// Fixed to be a valid usize.
const MY_CONST_USIZE: usize = usize::MAX;

fn my_rand_condition() -> bool { todo!(); }

fn example() {
    let vec1_of_A: Vec<A> = vec![];
    let vec2_of_A_refs: Vec<&A> = vec![];
    
    let my_iterator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=(usize, &A)>>;
    if my_rand_condition() {
        // Fixed to return x instead of &x
        my_iterator = Box::new(vec1_of_A.iter().map(|x| (MY_CONST_USIZE, x)));
    } else {
        // Added map to deref &&A to &A to make the types match
        my_iterator = Box::new(vec2_of_A_refs.iter().map(|x| *x).enumerate());
    }
    
    for item in my_iterator {
        // ...
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a717df128bc4dcce15cc7f4c8ef16c76))

Instead of a boxed trait object, you could also use the [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html) type from the `either` crate.  This is an enum with `Left` and `Right` variants, but the `Either` type itself implements `Iterator` if both the left and right types also do, with the same type for the `Item` associated type.  For example:

```
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use either::Either;

struct A;
const MY_CONST_USIZE: usize = usize::MAX;

fn my_rand_condition() -> bool { todo!(); }

fn example() {
    let vec1_of_A: Vec<A> = vec![];
    let vec2_of_A_refs: Vec<&A> = vec![];
    
    let my_iterator;
    if my_rand_condition() {
        my_iterator = Either::Left(vec1_of_A.iter().map(|x| (MY_CONST_USIZE, x)));
    } else {
        my_iterator = Either::Right(vec2_of_A_refs.iter().map(|x| *x).enumerate());
    }
    
    for item in my_iterator {
        // ...
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=93f00ceb67d9cb59e7e9244e05a11c98))

Why would you choose one approach over the other?

Pros of the `Either` approach:

- It does not require a heap allocation to store the iterator.
- It implements dynamic dispatch via `match` which is likely (but not guaranteed) to be faster than dynamic dispatch via vtable lookup.

Pros of the boxed trait object approach:

- It does not depend on any external crates.
- It scales easily to many different types of iterators; the `Either` approach quickly becomes unwieldy with more than two types.

Comment: thanks for crate info, also +1 for my `usize` mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a `Box`ed trait object like so:

```rust
let my_iterator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = _>> = if my_rand_condition() {
    Box::new(vec1_of_A.iter().map(|x| (MY_CONST_USIZE, x)))
} else {
    Box::new(vec2_of_A_refs.iter().enumerate().map(|(i, x)| (i, *x)))
};
```

I don't think this is a good idea generally though. A few things to note:

- The use of trait objects means the types here must be resolved dynamically. This adds a lot of overhead.
- The closure in `vec1`'s iterator's `map` method cannot reference its arguments. Instead the second `map` must be added to `vec2`s iterator. The effect of this is that all the items are being copied regardless. If you are doing this, why not `collect()`? The overhead for creating the `Vec` or whatever you choose should be less than that of the dynamic resolution.
- Bit pedantic, but remember `if` statements are expressions in Rust, and so the assignment can be expressed a little more cleanly as I have done above.